# Can I use Django REST with custom structures on serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a project in which I would like to be able to create a serializer that isn't based on a model and that could accept a custom structure of my choice.

Example:

```
class OptionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    option_1 = serializers.IntegerField()
    option_2 = serializers.IntegerField()
    option_3 = serializers.IntegerField()
    option_4 = serializers.IntegerField()
    option_5 = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('option_1', 'option_2', 'option_3', 'option_4', 'option_5')


class QuestionsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    questions = OptionSerializer(data=[], many=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('questions',)
```

In this example, I would have a custom object called Questions that would have an array of objects, each one containing the keys 'option_1', 'option_2', 'option_3', 'option_4' and 'option_5'. My goal would be to use something like this in a GenericAPIView that would allow me to render a similar structure when attempting a POST operation with the browsable API, and also to minimize validation efforts.

Is that possible to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do something like this.

```
class OptionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    option_1 = serializers.IntegerField()
    option_2 = serializers.IntegerField()
    option_3 = serializers.IntegerField()
    option_4 = serializers.IntegerField()
    option_5 = serializers.IntegerField()


class QuestionsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    questions = OptionSerializer(many=True)
```

You can then import this serializer in the view, and for a POST request, you can use it as:

```
serializer = QuestionsSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
```